# Combining strings with lambda expression

Tags: vb.net, arrays, lambda

I have a string array Array1 and a string array A2.  I want to combine these in a 3rd array A3 but excluding duplicate values.  Can this be done through lambda expressions or only through iterating through the array and checking array.Contains()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following

```
Dim newArray = array1.Union(array2).Distinct().ToArray()
```

This requires Visual Studio 2008 or higher (VB.Net 9.0).

Comment: You will additionally need a reference (not sure if it's termed the same in VB, I use C#) to Linq.

Comment: @BarretJ, in 2008 it is added as a project level Import so it should already be there

Comment: Aren't there only 2 overloads to Distinct()? No params and 1 that takes IEqualityComparer

Comment: Thanks it works.  I believe Distinct is unnecessary here as Union already returns the unique values.

Answer (score 1):

```
array1.Union(array2).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static Expression<Func<T, TResult>> And<T, TResult>(this Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TResult>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }
```